# How to select elements containing special characters in XPath?

Tags: html, xml, xpath, special-characters

I am trying to exclude three `<td>` elements from a result set:

```
<td>
    &#x1F947;
</td>
<td>
    &#x1F948;
</td>
<td>
    &#x1F949;
</td>
```

I've tried using:

```
td[not(contains(., '&#x1F948;'))]
```

For example, but the element I don't want still comes back...

Answer (score 0):

In the xpath expression, you need to use the escape conventions of the host language. Using &-escaping is fine if the host is XSLT, but if it’s JavaScript, for example, you’ll need to use backslash escaping.

Comment: True, but in many cases it's possible (and a better expression of intent) to just [copy-and-paste the literal Unicode character](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69515518/290085).

Answer (score 0):

To avoid the labyrinth of escaping conventions, just use literal Unicode characters themselves, which can be searched and then copy-and-pasted from sites such as [Compart](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/):

| Char Entity Ref | Literal Unicode | XPath |
| --- | --- | --- |
| [`&#x1F947;`](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+1F947) |  | `//td[not(contains(.,''))]` |
| [`&#x1F948;`](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+1F948) |  | `//td[not(contains(.,''))]` |
| [`&#x1F949;`](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+1F949) |  | `//td[not(contains(.,''))]` |

Here's a single XPath 2.0+ expression that will select all `td` elements in the document *except* those consisting of *only* the targeted special characters:

```
//td[not(normalize-space() = ('', '',''))]
```

In XPath 1.0, you'd have to write out the clauses separately:

```
//td[not(normalize-space() = '') and 
     not(normalize-space() = '') and 
     not(normalize-space() = '')]
```

Rearrange via DeMorgan's per taste.  Go back to `contains()` if you truly want to test via substring containment rather than string value equality.